# What's wrong with gimp alpha channel

Tags: gimp

My alpha channel for some reason is white instead of white and gray is there anyway I can change the solid color to multi color .

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  Do you mean you can't see the chequerboard pattern that indicates transparency?

Comment: in a color-indexed image (GIF, typically, and some PNG) the alpha-channel is binary (only fully opaque or fully transparent) because this is what the GIF format supports, so gray values would be thresholded to black or white (threshold=127)

Answer (score 0):

Alpha channels only show transparency. This is why they are only in black and white. White (100% shown), black (100% hidden) and gray (in-between see-through) are all that is needed to encode transparency. So, **changing your alpha channel to be in color is a no-can-do**. Perhaps you wanted to use layer *masks* instead to selectively show or hide colors on a layer?

If it's many-shades-of-gray-***alpha layer shading*** on the other hand, you can just grab a black or gray brush and paint away on that alpha channel to get some quick transparency. Selections may also help you quickly edit this, too.